# Finitely generated subgroups of the absolute Galois group

Tags: gr.group-theory, galois-theory, profinite-groups

Consider the absolute Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q})$. It seems to me that, in general, providing an "explicit" description of the elements of this group is a difficult task, see e.g. the related questions [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2791/understanding-mathrmgal-bar-mathbbq-mathbbq?rq=1) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6802/element-in-the-absolute-galois-group-of-the-rationals). To make everything easier, I will assume we are working in ZFC.

I am interested in what is known about the (abstractly) finitely generated subgroups of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q})$. To be clear, I do not mean topologically finitely generated here, but rather just subgroups $H < \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q})$ such that $H = \langle h_1, h_2, \dots, h_k \rangle$ for some elements $h_i \in \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q})$. Of course, $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q})$ itself is uncountable, so in particular not finitely generated in this sense.

The abstract properties of such finitely generated subgroups are of particular interest; to give some explicit questions:

1. **Are all finitely generated subgroups of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q})$ finitely presented?**
2. **Do all such subgroups have finite cohomological dimension?**
3. **Are all such subgroups residually finite and/or Hopfian?**

but any similar type of abstract properties would also be interesting! Any "easy" explicit example of a finitely generated subgroup (other than $1$, or $C_2$ via conjugation!) of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q})$ would also be of interest -- especially if such an example is defined by (finitely many) generators and relations.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really a question about the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$. For example every such group is residually finite and hence Hopfian simply since it is a subgroup of a profinite group. Also, we know that every subgroup of the free profinite group $\hat{F}_\omega$ on countably many generators occurs - is it possible even there to say what they are?

Comment: There is work on the finitely generated subgroups of the profinite completions of free groups. For instance, all *parafree* groups can occur (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parafree_group), and it is also known that Sela's limit groups all occur too. That said,  classification seems a long way off.

Comment: @ArnoFehm That is interesting -- do you have a reference to $\hat{F}_\omega$ appearing as a subgroup?

Comment: $\hat{F}_\omega$ is the absolute Galois group of any countable Hilbertian PAC field of characteristic zero by a result of Fried-Völklein, and there are plenty of these algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. See for example Jarden's Large normal extension of Hilbertian fields in Math. Z. 224, 1997.