# Roadmap for the ideas expressed in Grothendieck's Esquisse d'un Programme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, big-list

I would like to understand Grothendieck's Esquisse d'un Programme more. Are there any references that would help me, and are there modern works pursuing the same themes?

At this point I am still currently learning algebraic geometry, but I am familiar with the idea of moduli spaces as parametrizing families of curves (or more general objects) as well as the fundamental group from algebraic topology. I would like to know more as to what I should study next if I am interested in the ideas presented in the Esquisse d'un Programme.

Comment: Look here: http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/geometric-galois-actions-volume-1

Comment: As Esquisse has several distinct threads it would help if you gave more precision on what parts you want to concentrate on.

Comment: I think that this MO question about Grothendieck's Dessins d'Enfants could be of interest to you:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1909/what-are-dessins-denfants
You may begin with this part of his Esquisse.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses! If I had to be specific I guess I find the second and third sections to be the most interesting, which I believe concerns moduli and Teichmuller spaces, the projective line with three points removed, and the already mentioned Dessins d'Enfants. I will certainly check out the links provided. And I hope it's okay to add this question here, but what does Grothendieck mean by "modular multiplicities"? Is he referring to stacks?